# Calling the database from getStaticProps in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was watching a nextjs tutorial and the instructor did something that kind of breaks what I learn in school and left me thinking.

He did this:

```
interface FaqProps {
  faq: FaqModel[];
}

export default function Faq({ faq }: FaqProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {faq.map((f) => (
        <ExpansionPanel key={f.id}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary
            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
            id="panel1a-header"
          >
            <Typography>{f.question}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Typography>{f.answer}</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const db = await openDB();
  const faq = await db.all("SELECT * FROM FAQ ORDER BY createDate DESC");
  return { props: { faq } };
};
```

What I understood, because the faq never change, I can load them at build time, calling `getStaticProps`. Because `getStaticProps` only happens in the server I can call
directly to the database.

So, is okay to do this instead of doing a fetch call to the server?
Aren't pattern being broken here?
Is this where the web development is going or is just something this person does?

Comment: ["...you can write server-side code directly in `getStaticProps`. This includes reading from the filesystem or a database."](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)

Comment: Yes, I know it can be done. I just want to know if it is a good practice to do this

Comment: It's fine to do this. It's a feature of Next.js and if it was bad practice to do so, then Vercel wouldn't even mention it in the documentation, or at the very least would put a disclaimer that you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

To cite a quote directly from [the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#write-server-side-code-directly):

> #### Write server-side code directly
>
> Note that `getStaticProps` runs only on the server-side. It will never be run on the client-side. It won’t even be included in the JS bundle for the browser. That means you can write code such as direct database queries without them being sent to browsers. You should not fetch an **API route** from `getStaticProps` — instead, you can write the server-side code directly in `getStaticProps`.

I think it's made pretty clear that this pattern is not only allowed, but encouraged. [`getStaticProps` was introduced in Next.js 9.3 and is recommended over `getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) when static generation at build-time is preferred over server-side rendering at run-time. In contrast with `getStaticProps`, the `getInitialProps` function *is* bundled with the client-side code and *can* potentially run in the browser.

Comment: `getStaticProps` is only executed once at build time is that correct? What is then the point in making a database query if I only get the data at build time and never again after that? Or am I missing something completely here?

Comment: @Mirco if your database has tables that aren't expected to change often (even if it's as often as once an hour), I believe that when developing with Next.js the typical practice is to rebuild the static pages by restarting the server with a cron job or other timed service. While it seems like a lot of work upfront, the purpose is to decrease the TTFB metric as low as possible for what can practically be considered static content.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

For the future reader, regarding the point of creating static pages with `getStaticProps` and then rebuilding to update the props, I would like to add that along with the `props` object, you can return `revalidate: 60` (with 60 being just an example here) which will re-evaluate the code in `getStaticProps` every 60 seconds. If you expect that your data will not change in the next hour, you can `revalidate` in 3600 seconds or accordingly.